# ORA-01830: incorrect date with timestamp from Postgresql to Oracle format

Tags: postgresql, oracle

I have the following Timestamp With Time Zone column value in Postgresql:

```
2011-09-13 07:38:01+00
```

Which I convert to the necessary Date format expected by Oracle in the select:

```
select to_char(date_column, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24.MM.SS') as date_column from table;
```

Which matches the Date format expected by Oracle or NLS mask. Upon inserting the row into Oracle through the ETL process however, this error is thrown:

```
ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string
```

Any ideas what may fix the conversion correctly?

Comment: 1) That is not a `date` it is a `timestamp(datetime)` 2) I have a hard time believing Oracle can't accept an ISO formatted timestamp 3) If this `select to_date(...)` is being done on Postgres that will produce a `date` not a `timestamp`. For that you would need `to_timestamp(...)`. See here [Formatting functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html).  4) ` select to_date('2011-09-13 07:38:01+00', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24.MM.SS'); ERROR:  conflicting values for "MM" field in formatting string`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I assume `date_column` is holding a value `2011-09-13 07:38:01+00` and thus its datatype would be `VARCHAR2`. In such case, you can first get zone `+00` trimmed using `SUBSTR`, and then applying 'to_date' with a compatible format should give a date.

`select to_date(SUBSTR(date_column, 1, 19), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MM:SS') as date_column from table;`

Comment: The date_column is a Timezone with Time Stamp in Postgresql, which I am trying to insert into a Date column in Oracle

Comment: @bullfighter I guess my answer resolves the question. If so, show some courtesy by upvoting or marking it as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

In this query

```
select to_date(date_column, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24.MM.SS') as date_column from table;
```

You have "MM" for **MONTH** and **MINUTES** both, try switching to acceptable format. As per my knowledge "MI"  is used for minutes.  This might help.

```
SELECT TO_DATE(date_column, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS date_column FROM table;
```

Comment: Yeah, good point - both variants work, but MI is the correct in this case as you point out