# Postgresql: Remove Timezone from Timestamp, but maintain datatype as timestamp?

Tags: postgresql

I have quite a headache of an issue. I am moving a Timestamp with time zone field in Postgresql to a Date (datetime) column in Oracle, using an ETL tool.

The Postgresql Timestamp column (named psql_column) has values such as:

```
2011-09-13 07:37:24+00
```

While Oracle expects values in the form of:

```
DD.MM.YYYY HH24.MI.SS
```

I have tried several queries on the Postgresql table to retreive the values in a manner suitable to Oracle, such as:

```
to_char(psql_column, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24.MI.SS')
```

Which oracle does not want to accept for some reason (throws ORA-01830)?
Then the following line casts the value back to a date value:

```
to_date(to_char(psql_column, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24.MI.SS'), 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24.MI.SS')
```

But this ofcourse only returns the value back to the original Postgresql date format, which Oracle doesn't accept.

Comment: Quit asking the same question [over](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76590004/ora-01830-incorrect-date-with-timestamp-from-postgresql-to-oracle-format)  and [over](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76595596/ora-01830-date-with-time-insert). You might also want to read this [Oracle default date formats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50163432/oracles-default-date-format).

Comment: This is another side to the problem - same overall issue, but honing into the Postgresql component of what I am working on, NOT the Oracle side of things.

Comment: Read your question in particular: *Which oracle does not want to accept for some reason (throws ORA-01830)?* and *But this ofcourse only returns the value back to the original Postgresql date format, which Oracle doesn't accept.* . The issue is on the Oracle side of things not in Postgres per: `select to_char('2023-07-01 11:45'::timestamp, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24.MI.SS')  01.07.2023 11.45.00`.  Postgres is delivering what you are asking for.

Comment: The issue is ultimately due to schema reconciliation in the ETL tool. I can format the date correctly out from Postgres, yes, but it will be in a char-type, which tries to insert a value of the format 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24.MI.SS' as a string to Oracle, which will keep throwing the ORA-01830 error. So one way to fix this would be to cast to timestamp in postgres, but fix the format it returns it as - otherwise the format won't match and be accepted by Oracle

Comment: My apologies, I found the fix just now. Simply casting the column to a regular Timestamp in Postgresql removes the timezone component, which is what I assume Oracle was complaining about in the first place.

Comment: There is no time zone component in `'DD.MM.YYYY HH24.MI.SS'` or it's output `01.07.2023 11.45.00`. I'm betting that the actual issue was with this format `'DD.MM.YYYY HH24.MI.SS'` instead of using `2011-09-13 07:37:24` or `YYYY-MM-DD HH24.MI.SS`

Answer (score 0):

try this format, I guess it should work:)

```
to_date(to_char(psql_column, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

Comment: The bottom line returns the Psql format for timestamp, ie.

"2013-08-18 02:00:59.000000+00:00"

Which doesn't suit with Oracle's format - so the last parts need to get removed.

Comment: @bullfighter got you:) fixed answer

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it's the same line I tried in the last line of my OP :D It returns only the value back to the psql date formal of 2013-08-18, without the time component (which is needed)